# Most concise way to copy portion of large slice

Tags: go

I was reading [this](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals) blog article (last section on "A possible gotcha"), which discusses how to copy a part of a large slice into a new smaller slice so the large slice can be garbage collected.

The code they provide is:

```
func CopyDigits(filename string) []byte {
    b, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
    b = digitRegexp.Find(b)
    c := make([]byte, len(b))
    copy(c, b)
    return c
}
```

The article suggests that there is a more concise way this function can be constructed using an `append`. I'm assuming something like this, but I don't see the point of doing it this way:

```
func CopyDigits(filename string) []byte {
    b, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
    b = digitRegexp.Find(b)
    return append(make([]byte, len(b)), b...)
}
```

This would also make the code less efficient since it appears that `append` is implemented using `copy`. Since this copying into a new slice is a fairly common operation, what's the best way to do it?

Comment: Use the first example; it makes the reader think less. Reevaluate if/when you have data of that being a bottleneck in your application.

Comment: Your second example is incorrect, as it's going to return a slice with a length of `2*b` (even after you add the missing `...`). Probably a great example of why trying to write it in as little code as possible may make it harder to understand or lead to needless bugs.

Comment: Your second example does not compile, and it will do the wrong thing when the "..." is added to fix the compilation error.

Comment: Makes me wonder why it was even mentioned... Figured there was no more efficient way than the simple copy they provided.

Comment: @jiaweizhang: it's mentioned simply because it's possible. "Abusing" `append` in this manner isn't uncommon, but it's often surprising to see something like `return append([]byte(nil), b...)`, and you have to stop and think a second what that does. I'd rather just have it spelled out in code, especially since they _should_ compile to the same thing.

Comment: @JimB and what  about `b = digitRegexp.Find(b)` and then `return b`? I would expect that bytes cutted of will be released to garbage collector..

Comment: @bigless: No, the entire point of this exercise was to demonstrate how to allow the original slice to be garbage collected. There are no bytes "cut off"; `b` is a sub-slice of the full slice returned by `ReadFile` and points at the same backing array.

Answer (score 0):

Just finished reading the same blog today. Noticed the exercise at the bottom and decided to give it a go (pun intended :D).

Stumbled on to this question and was wondering if my answer is the concise version using append that the blog was talking about.

```
func CopyDigits(filename string) []byte {
    b, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
    b = digitRegexp.Find(b)

    var c []byte
    return append(c, b...)
}
```

Curious about other versions of the same. :)